# which is the better way to create an object of Outlook MaiItem

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, createobject, mailitem

I found two ways to create an object of Outlook mailItem

```
Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

and

```
 Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

What is the diffrence between these two codes and Which one is better and secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is in a COM addin, the first one is the one and only way to do it - use the Outlok.Application object passed to your addin instead of creating a new instance. COM addins are trusted, and the Outlok.Application object is not crippled by the security prompts.